# Why is React delaying state variable value change but instantly updating the local variable

Tags: reactjs

Here is the example code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Lab() {
    let selectedColor = '';
    const cars = [
        { make: 'Tesla', color: 'black' },
        { make: 'Ford', color: 'white' },
        { make: 'Toyota', color: 'red' }
    ];

    const [selectedMake, setSelectedMake] = useState('');

    const handleClick = (e, make, color) => {

        // Update the state variable
        setSelectedMake(make);
        console.log(selectedMake);
        
        // Update the local variable
        selectedColor = color;
        console.log(selectedColor);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                cars.map ((car, i) => <button onClick={e => handleClick(e, car.make, car.color)}>{car.make}</button>) 
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Lab;
```

And here is how the result is behaving:

[image: Misbehaving result]

It is strange it updates the local variable immediately, but for the state variable, it is not updating the value immediately but with a delay and I am getting the updated value only in next render? What is causing this? and how can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `setSelectedMake` is asynchronous (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) , your console.log will display the last state. Try to log your variable with :

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedMake)
}, [selectedMake]);
```

On mount, and when `selectedMake` change, it'll fired the function in the `useEffect`. To avoid log on mount, just wrap it with a if statement :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedMake) {
        console.log(selectedMake)
    }
}, [selectedMake]);
```